# Relation between conjugate subgroups and the subgroup generated by them

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group with $H\leq G$. Suppose that $g\in G$ and $y\in \langle H, gHg^{-1}\rangle$.

If $yHy^{-1}$ and $gHg^{-1}$ are conjugate in $\langle yHy^{-1}, gHg^{-1}\rangle$, then $H$ and $gHg^{-1}$ are conjugate in $\langle H, gHg^{-1}\rangle$.

I have that $x(yHy^{-1})x^{-1} = gHg^{-1}$ for some $x\in \langle yHy^{-1}, gHg^{-1}\rangle$. If I can show that $x\in \langle H, gHg^{-1}\rangle$ then I would be done. To do this I need to show $\langle yHy^{-1}, gHg^{-1}\rangle \leq\langle H, gHg^{-1}\rangle$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $y \in \langle H, gHg^{-1}\rangle$, you immediately have $\langle yHy^{-1}, gHg^{-1}\rangle \leq \langle H, gHg^{-1}\rangle$ because of course $H$ is *also* a subgroup of $\langle H, gHg^{-1}\rangle$ (i.e. $yhy^{-1} \in \langle H, gHg^{-1}\rangle$ because both $y$ and $h$ are, hence $yHy^{-1} \leq \langle H, gHg^{-1}\rangle$ and therefore $\langle yHy^{-1}, gHg^{-1}\rangle \leq \langle H, gHg^{-1}\rangle$).

Now, as you rightly claim, you are done, because you have $x(yHy^{-1})x^{-1} = gHg^{-1}$ for some $x \in \langle yHy^{-1}, gHg^{-1}\rangle$. But by what we said in the paragraph above, we thus have $x\in \langle H, gHg^{-1}\rangle$ so therefore $xy \in \langle H, gHg^{-1}\rangle$ too and $(xy)H(xy)^{-1} = x(yHy^{-1})x^{-1} = gHg^{-1}$.

Comment: This is great! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome :)